# Drawing McCulloch-Pitts Neurons

Tags: diagrams, nodes, graphs

I'm looking for a latex package to draw McCulloch-Pitts Neurons and Neural Networks. I've searched the TikZ examples but did not find anything suitable.

I need different style for inverted inputs (circle at the connection) and the ability to put a threshold in each node.

Idealy I want it look like in the image
[image]

Comment: Use [`circuitikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz).

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I do not want anybody  drawing something for me. I am only looking for a latex package that allows me to draw in the fashion of the given example. The example was not made by me. I know about packages to draw graphs in latex but are there any that allow me to draw nodes with a split and a text inside them and that allow to specify on what side edges connect and that allow cirecles to be added at a connection point?